# Use Google Charting library to make a GeoChart which isn't showing

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

everyone. I have a problem. I am making a web page and I want to include a GeoChart in it. The problem is that even when I directly copy-paste from the Google developer's website and incorporate the code into the pre-existing one, the map doesn't show. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

This is the JavaScript portion:-

```
<script>
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['geochart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

        function drawRegionsMap()
        {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Country', 'Popularity'],
            ['Germany', 200],
            ['United States', 300],
            ['Brazil', 400],
            ['Canada', 500],
            ['France', 600],
            ['RU', 700]
            ]);

            var options = {};

            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
</script>
```

This is the HTML portion:-

```
<div=id='regions_div' style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Your script block seems incorrect!. It starts and ends with </script>.

Comment: @DavidR oh lol that's actually a typo. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

looks like the main problem is the extra `=` in the `div` definition, here...
`<div=id='regions_div' style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>`

as such, the chart cannot find the container, which is being reported in the browser console.

change to...
`<div id='regions_div' style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>`

also, be sure to load both libraries -- `loader.js` & `jsapi`

following is a working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700]
    ]);

    var options = {};
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['geochart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id='regions_div' style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: it's still not working though. The space is allotted to it but it does not show/load (the GeoChart).